# Проблемы с border-radius в owl-carousel

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, sass, carousel

Есть шестиугольник (Ссылка на [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/junior-web-dev/pen/qqyEpB?editors=1100)).
Если засунуть его в owl-carousel ломается `border-radius` в Edge и Mozila отображается нормально, в Яндекс-браузере и Опере слетает. При этом когда движется слайд `border-radius` есть, когда останавливается — `border-radius` исчезает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Должно так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
dev tool:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**HTML**

```
<div class="hexagon">
<div class="six">
    <div class="inner-six1"></div>
    <div class="inner-six2"></div>
    <div class="inner-six3"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

**SASS**

```
.hexagon
    margin: 0 auto
    padding: 70px
    outline: 1px solid black
    text-align: center
.six
    display: inline-block
    position: relative
    width: 220px
    height: 150px
    .inner-six1,.inner-six2,.inner-six3
        border-radius: 30px
        overflow: hidden
        position: absolute
        width: inherit
        height: 100%
        &:before
            content: ""
            position: absolute
            width: 100%
            height: 246px
            top: 0
            left: 0
            background: url("https://fshoke.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Arnold-Schwarzenegger-mixed-with-Sylvester-Stallone.jpg") 50% 50% / cover no-repeat
    .inner-six1/* ELEMENT 1 */
        transform: rotate(60deg)
        &:before
            transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(42px, -23px)
    .inner-six2/* ELEMENT 2 */
        transform: rotate(-60deg)
        &:before
            transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-42px, -23px)
    .inner-six3/* ELEMENT 2 */
        &:before
            transform: translateY(-47px)
```

Comment: Видно ведь что третьему блоку не применяется border-radius. Через developer tools смотрели? Может быть другие свойства для последнего элемента в конечном файле начинают перекрывать его бордер радиус.

Comment: В developer tools для всех 3х элементов свойство применяется, border-radius не перечеркнут, но по факту его нет, вот что удивляет) буду копаться, смотреть что не так, если что напишу тут, за любую помощь в вопросе спасибо!

Comment: Понял что border-radius слетает только когда он в owl-carousel за пределами все нормально, ищу ошибку дальше...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел подшипник! )

Кстати, если задать последнему элементу border, то видно что все таки border-radius работает, но before или еще кто-то игнорит его.

Решил это тем, что применил для элемента transform/rotate(0)? остальные ведь тоже имеют это свойство:)

Костыль, но работает. Если ничего внятного не сделаешь, используй :)

Решение тут -
[codepen](http://codepen.io/sashakrauzer/pen/XNPvox)

```
.inner-six3/* ELEMENT 3 */
    border-radius: 30px
    transform: rotate(0deg)
```

Comment: И правда это единственное чем они отличаются) сказать что меня удивляет такое поведение элемента это все равно что промолчать) Спасибо большое)

Comment: @junior-web-dev если помог, отметьте как решение :)